# move the div upon checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, css-selectors

I am trying to implement a elevator functionality [there are 6 floors and corresponding
   to each one , there is a checkbox. Depending upon which checkbox is checked, the elevator
   shud move to that floor.

But the functionality somehow seems to be not working.

Here is my HTMl markup with embedded jquery script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Sample Page</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $('.container input').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            if ($('div.activeDiv')[0]) {
           $(".blockdiv>div").removeClass("activeDiv");}
           $(this).closest('.blockdiv .inactiveDiv').addClass("activeDiv");
    }
    });

    </script>
    <style> .blockDiv {   
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #0000FF;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.activeDiv{
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #FFAC00;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.inactiveDiv{
    background: #0000FF;
}</style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="blockDiv">
                    <div class="inactiveDiv"></div>
                </div>            
            <input type="checkbox" name="floorCheck" value="fifthFloor"/>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="blockDiv">
                    <div class="inactiveDiv"></div>
                </div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="floorCheck" value="fourthFloor"/>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="blockDiv">
                    <div class="inactiveDiv"></div>
                </div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="floorCheck" value="thirdFloor"/>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="blockDiv">
                    <div class="inactiveDiv"></div>
                </div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="floorCheck" value="secondFloor"/>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="blockDiv">
                    <div class="inactiveDiv"></div>
                </div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="floorCheck" value="firstFloor"/>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="blockDiv">
                    <div class="activeDiv"></div>
                </div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="floorCheck" value="groundFloor"/>
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the inactive clas and add active class

try this

```
$(function(){ //this is to call the script only after document is ready
  $('.container input').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

      $(".blockDiv > div").removeClass("activeDiv");
      $(this).siblings('.blockDiv').find('.inactiveDiv').addClass("activeDiv");

    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks bipen for all the help.
Could u please help me out in showing the orange div moving from one floor to other. To make it look more live and animated.

Answer (score 0):

Start by wrapping the JS in a document ready handler, or it won't be able to find your elements. (Or move the script to the end of the body.)

Then update your CSS to define the `.activeDiv` class after `.inactiveDiv` so that if an element has both classes `.activeDiv` will override `.inactiveDiv` - that way you don't have to worry about removing `.inactiveDiv`, you can just add and remove `.activeDiv`.

Then note that your existing code `$(this).closest('.blockdiv .inactiveDiv')` won't find anything because `.closest()` traverses *up* through the DOM and the `.blockDiv` elements are siblings of the checkboxes, not parents, so instead either use the `.prev()` method or use `.closest('.container')` to get the parent and then `.find('.blockDiv .inactiveDiv')` to come back down to the block div.

```
  $('.container input').change(function () {
      if (this.checked) {
          $(".blockDiv > div").removeClass("activeDiv");
          $(this).closest('.container').find('.blockDiv .inactiveDiv').addClass("activeDiv");
      }
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rrCam/

Note also that `this.checked` is simpler and faster than `$(this).is(':checked')`.

Comment: Thank you so much nnnnnn.
I am just thinking if it is possible to show the orange div moving from one floor to other. To make it look more live and animated.